# Incompatible types java.util.List double

Tags: java

How to resolve this issue?

```
 public List<Double> getIntermediateGrade(){
    List<Evaluation> evaluationList = evaluationRepository.getAll();
    List<Double> evaluationGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (Evaluation evaluation : evaluationList){
        evaluationGrades = evaluation.getIntermidiateGrade();//error here

    }
    return evaluationGrades;
}
```

The error is:

```
Incompatible types: java.util.List <java.util.Double> , Double
```

How to change the line inside the for in order to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a careless error as you're trying to equate a List with a Double. Instead you want to add to the list, so change

```
evaluationGrades = evaluation.getIntermidiateGrade();
```

to

```
evaluationGrades.add(evaluation.getIntermidiateGrade());
```

Lesson: the error messages don't lie and will often tell you exactly what's wrong. Look closely at the message and the line and look for your mistake.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, next time I will be more careful.